# Saving "Select Multiple" values in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, select

I have from where teachers can select multiple options (each option represents a skill they posses).

The form looks like this

```
@model Ability.Models.ViewModel

<h2>Add Skill</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select multiple name="AddSkillForm">
        @foreach (var skill in Model.Skills)
        {
            <option value="@skill.ID">@skill.SkillName</option>
        }          
    </select>
</form>
```

As you can see, they can select more then one option.

My **database** looks like this

[image]

Now I was wondering how I can succesfully save the data in my form. I was thinking of using a url that looks like

> teacher/addskills/1

Where "1" represents the Teacher_ID and ofcourse the skill_ID's are given though the form.

My question is, how can I pass the multiple values too my controller and save them correctly in my DB?

Looking forward to any help!

Comment: Create a class that maps your POST request values.

Comment: Dude, generating a dropdownlist with a `@foreach` statement, seriously?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov What's wrong that? What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: There is a helper method for this `@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Skills)` I'm not sure that there is anything wrong with a foreach for this *per se* but it's probably cleaner and more maintainable if you use the helper method.

Comment: The correct way is to use a view model in conjunction with the `Html.ListBoxFor` strongly typed helper.

Comment: Why don't you use a ListBox with multi select?

Comment: @Coulton, the `@Html.DropDownFor` helper that you are referring to is not designed for handling multiple selections which is what the OP seems to need here. The `Html.ListBoxFor` helper is a more appropriate candidate for this job.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has 2 up votes, it doesn't contain enough information to answer it.  What method have you chosen for interacting with the database, stored procs, Entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Darin suggested.

> The correct way is to use a view model in conjunction with the
>   Html.ListBoxFor strongly typed helper

I would use a multi select ListBox. The model binder will take care of the rest.

**Model view**

```
        public class MyModelView
        {
           public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Skills{ get; set; }
           public string[] SelectedSkills { get; set; } // You could use      List<string> instead. 
           public int TeacherId {get;set;}
        }
```

**View**

```
     @Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedSkills , 
    new MultiSelectList(Model.Skills, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedSkills ), 
    new { @class = "form-control", style = "height:250px; width:100%" })
     @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.TeacherId)
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Save(MyModelView model)
     {
       foreach (string skill in model.SelectedSkills){//Selected Skills. Save to database}
     }
```

**EDIT**

Get skills from database. Based on your database structure you should be able to get all skills per teacher from the bridge table "TeacherSkills". You will need to fill you SelectedSkills property where Skills should have all the available skills.

```
 List<SelectListItem> selectedSkills= service.GetSkillsByTeacherId(teacherId);

if (selectedSkills != null && selectedSkills.Count > 0)
{
   model.SelectedSkills = selectedSkills.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this out and let you know how it goes

Comment: I'm sorry, We're having trouble writing the query to get all the skills out of the DB. We're trying something like this     
            {
                Skills = (from s in db.Skills
                          select s)
            }; but it's obviously wrong, how we should write the correct query then?

Comment: Not a problem Nicolas. I've updated the answer, let me know how it goes.